Dynamically set the printed page size using '@page'
I want to print labels of 2 sizes - 3X2inches and 3x3inches.
Bydefault I have set the label print page size as 3x2inches in styles.scss (Global file).
@page {
    size: 3in 2in;
}

I now want to select the 3x3in label. After selecting the dropdown option and clicking the 'Print' button, how can I dynamically change the printed page size in typescript or CSS using class?
// Want to set new page size dynamically to following
@page {
    size: 3in 3in;
}


You can achieve this with CSS variables and @property:
@property --page-height {
  syntax: "<length>";
  inherits: true;
  initial-value: 2in;
}

@page {
  size: 3in var(--page-height);
}

This will create a new CSS variable and default it to 2in. Then you can provide a new value for the variable via JavaScript like the following:
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--page-height', '3in');


This is amazing! It worked! Thank you @JSON Derulo
